# Simple 2D application, having trouble with glutBitmapCharacter

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I am trying to simply write anything on the screen. Drawing rectangles is easy enough. I am trying to place a text string sideways superimposed on a "book". It seems very simple and yet...

Just as a note, I tried to take advice from these forums so `glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);` and `glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);` are probably not necessary. Additionally, is there a way to enable debugging myself? I am usually a fan of adding `cout << "i reached this far yay" << endl;` but it doesn't seem to like me when I place it in `void Bookshelf()`... it gives me a C2381 error (`'function' : redefinition; __declspec(noreturn) differs`)

main.cpp

```
#include "bookshelf.h"

void Initialize()
{
    glClearColor (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0 );
    glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
    glOrtho(0,899,899,0,1,0);
}
void main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    glutInit( &argc, argv );
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB );
    glutInitWindowSize( 900, 900 );
    glutInitWindowPosition( 510, 100 );
    glutCreateWindow("Bookshelf - Ankit Ahuja");
    Initialize();
    glutDisplayFunc(Bookshelf);
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

bookshelf.h

```
#include <GL/glut.h>  

void Bookshelf()
{
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );
    glColor3f( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 );
    glBegin( GL_QUADS );

    //Code that draws a bookshelf
    //Book1
    glColor3f( 1.0, 0.25, 0.25 );
    glVertex3i(240,70,0.5);
    glVertex3i(260,70,0.5);
    glVertex3i(260,180,0.5);
    glVertex3i(240,180,0.5);

    //BookTitle1
    glPushMatrix();
    glLoadIdentity();
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glRotatef(90f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
    glColor3f( 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 );
    glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glRasterPos3i(100,100,1);

    char text[50]="Alphabet Soup is the best guys";
    for(int i=0; i<50; i++) 
    {
        glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_9_BY_15,(int)text[i]);
    }
    glPopMatrix();

    //Book2
    glColor3f( 0.8, 0.8, 0.0 );
    glVertex2i(270,70);
    glVertex2i(290,70);
    glVertex2i(290,180);
    glVertex2i(270,180);

    //More books and shelves
    glEnd();
    glFlush();
}
```

Comment: Please properly format your code

Comment: What have you been able to draw to the screen?  What exactly do you want drawn?  If you provide some small thumbnails (even hand-drawn) of what is drawing and what isn't, it will better indicate the problems you are having.

Comment: I can draw all the rectangles without a problem, and have them filled in as intended, I just get stuck on the text part.

Comment: http://i47.tinypic.com/8zl95e.png is the portion of the project I can successfully create

Comment: update: text shows up but it is still not rotated properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set-up an orthographic projection by using the `glOrtho` before displaying your text.

Make sure you correctly push/pop the projection and modelview matrix before writing ur text so you are looking at something like:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);    //Select projection matrix
glPushMatrix();                 //save it
glLoadIdentity();                               

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);    //Select modelview matrix
glPushMatrix();                //save it
glLoadIdentity();          

// set up ur glOrtho
glOrtho(...);

glutBitmapCharacter(...)                  

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glPopMatrix();                //Restore your old projection matrix

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glPopMatrix();               //Restore old modelview matrix
```

Comment: this worked. However, do you have any idea how I can now rotate the text string?

Comment: use the glRotatef around your view axis if u want in 2d

Comment: unfortunately, glRotatef in any form is not working. after doing more research, i'm not sure it's possible. is there an alternative to glutBitmapCharacter that will rotate?

Comment: ok i find out it is not possible; try to use free font instead. There is a tut on nehe about this http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/2d_texture_font/18002/ you might find some more recent tut on google about this